# How to show progress of ack-grep

Tags: linux, bash, ack

I use "ack-grep" to search for a specific content within a large number of files.

Because the search takes a very long time, I would like to see the status of the search. For example: It would be very useful, if ack-grep would print out the actual searching path, instead showing just a blank screen while the searching process is in progress.

Does anyone know, how to make ack-grep printing out status-information while searching is in progress?

***Edit***
Here is the command I used until yet:

```
ack-grep StringToSearchFor --type=cc
```

Comment: What is ack-grep, just ack ?

Comment: ack-grep  is a grep-like text finder.
It is designed as a replacement for 99% of the uses of grep.

Comment: Debian and its variants package ack as "ack-grep" because there was already a package called "ack".

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but ack does not have any sort of progress indicator.

It may make more sense for you to use grep for your searching, unless you are using any ack-specific features.  Can you tell more about what it is that you're searching?  Is it all source code?

Comment: I added an example to my question above for you. I am searching for a string within source  code and only source code.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything weird there, and using --cc means you're only searching the files you need to be, so I don't know if there's anything you could do to speed things up, other than use grep.

Answer (score 0):

It is not what you are looking for, but maybe this helps

```
grep -H "you searched expression here" /your/path/here/*.php
```

It will grep in that dir (add -R if you need recursive) and you will see output as expression in found.
Or you can redirect output to a log file, and `tail -f logfile` so that you can see current current status

Answer (score 0):

If speed is your problem, rather than showing progress using `ack` you might look at using an alternative, `ag`, also known as the [the-silver-searcher](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/).

ag is not 100% compatible with ack - "It started off as a clone of Ack, but their feature sets have since diverged slightly. In typical usage, Ag is 5-10x faster than Ack."

Answer (score 0):

From https://serverfault.com/questions/343197/grep-progress-bar-using-pv-pipe-viewer/735274#735274

You can use the proc-filesystem on Linux systems, i.e.

`ls -al /proc/<pid of grep>/fd`

This lists all the files that the grep-process has open currently and thus provides information about where in the search it is currently.